# C# - Type or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, class, xunit

I'm trying to make a xUnit test for a simple class in the Windows app I have just started to write in C#. I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

My xUnit class don't accept "using" statement with namespace of the main project.

I tried to instead of Windows app, made Console app with the same class but when I build solution I receive the same error: CS0246
The type or namespace name 'HtmlRefactoringConsole' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The class in Console app looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HtmlRefactoringConsole
{
    public class Article
    {
        public string Title { get; }

        public string AuthorNameWithTitles { get; }

        public string InputRelativePath { get; }                                // relative path to the root directory of the Magazine 

        public string InputFileName { get; }

        private string ValidateNotNullAndNotWhiteSpace(string paramValue, string paramName)
        {
            if (paramValue == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"Invalid value! {paramName} is null.");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paramValue))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Invalid value! {paramName} is empty or contains only white-space character.");
            }
            return paramValue;
        }

        public Article(string title, string authorNameWithTitles, string inputRelativePath, string inputFileName)
        {
            Title = ValidateNotNullAndNotWhiteSpace(title, "Title");
            AuthorNameWithTitles = ValidateNotNullAndNotWhiteSpace(authorNameWithTitles, "AuthorNameWithTitles");
            InputRelativePath = ValidateNotNullAndNotWhiteSpace(inputRelativePath, "InputRelativePath");
            InputFileName = ValidateNotNullAndNotWhiteSpace(inputFileName, "InputFileName");
        }

        public string AuthorNameWithoutTitles()
        {
            return AuthorNameWithTitles;
        }

    }
}
```

xUnit class code is this one:

```
using HtmlRefactoringConsole;

namespace HtmlRefactoringTests
{
    public class ArticleTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ArticleConstruction_Title_()
        {
            const string title = "Title";

            var article = new Article(title, "", "", "");

            Assert.Equal(title, article.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

Full project code can be found here:
https://github.com/ivo-tisljar/html-refactoring

Comment: Did you reference the console app project in the unit test project?

Comment: Nope - there's no project reference here: https://github.com/ivo-tisljar/html-refactoring/blob/master/HtmlRefactoringTests/HtmlRefactoringTests.csproj

Comment: Now the xUnit test works fine with the Console app, but when I change the dependancy of the xUnit to Windows app I receive the following error: NU1201
Project HtmlRefactoringWindowsApp is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Project HtmlRefactoringWindowsApp supports: net6.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

Does that mean that I can't use xUnit with Windows app or am I missing something?
I have updated git hub to link to Windows app

Comment: No, it means that you need to change the target framework of the test project to net6.0-windows7.0 as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet - once again your comment strikes to the right point and helps me. Many thanks!

Comment: @JonSkeet - I was curious - who is the good Samaritan who gives such useful answers and I found out that you are contributor #1 on Stack Overflow. Wow!

As it happens I am learning C# and since I have found that you wrote book about it which received great reviews, as a small token of my gratitude and because quality of your answers is best recommendation for your book I'm going to buy it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different projects then you need to make the project reference to other where you want to use the class. If you dont have the reference then you are going to have this error "Type or Namespace could not be found". after giving the reference you can use the class by "**using**" keyword.

Give the console app reference to the XUnit project. it will be solved.